# PingException occurred mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, async-await, ping

I'm trying to read ip address from `.csv` file and ping those addresses using PingAsync class. But I'm getting above exception in the following line.

```
await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
```

my full code is Given below please take a look.

**Ping Method**

```
private static async Task AsyncPingTask(List<string> ipaddress)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping Started");
        StringBuilder pingStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


            var pingTasks = ipaddress.Select(ip =>
            {
                using (var ping = new Ping())
                {
                    return ping.SendPingAsync(ip);
                }
            }).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Ping Completed");

            await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);


            foreach (var pingReply in pingTasks)
            {
                pingStringBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.Address);
                pingStringBuilder.Append("-->");
                pingStringBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.Status);
                pingStringBuilder.Append("-->");
                pingStringBuilder.Append(pingReply.Result.RoundtripTime.ToString());
                pingStringBuilder.AppendLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(pingStringBuilder.ToString());
            pingStringBuilder.Clear();                

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        throw;
    }

    }
```

**Main Method:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> address = new List<string>();
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(Environment.CurrentDirectory+@"\address.csv"));
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var lines = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = lines.Split(';');
            address.Add(values[0]);
        }                
    });


    Console.WriteLine("List COunt is {0}",address.Count);
    Stopwatch timeSpan=Stopwatch.StartNew();


    t.Wait();            


    AsyncPingTask(address).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ElapsedMilliseconds);                        
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I done any mistake please guide me.

Comment: What is the exception message? Or rather, the innerexceptions message

Comment: Please at least read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193994(v=vs.110).aspx): "An exception was thrown while sending or receiving the ICMP messages. See the inner exception for the exact exception that was thrown." - so a `PingException`, in and of itself, tells us nothing. You need to debug this further yourself.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: An exception occurred during a Ping request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is the problem:

```
var pingTasks = ipaddress.Select(ip =>
{
    using (var ping = new Ping())
    {
        return ping.SendPingAsync(ip);
    }
}).ToList();
```

You're disposing the `Ping` class before the `async` operation has a chance to complete, since you're not awaiting on `SendPingAsync`, but simply returning the hot task it produces. This leads the the disposal prior to the completion of the operation.

Change your code to:

```
var pingTasks = ipaddress.Select(ip =>
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    return ping.SendPingAsync(ip);
}).ToList();
```

Comment: It's working fine without reading **.csv file** . I just copied all the ip addresses from the file created list by myself it's working fine. Why that's throwing error while using **.csv file**?

Comment: @SarathJasrin Even if it's working fine, you have a race condition there. Which error is thrown?

Comment: Hi! @yuval itzchakov thanks for your reply! I have done a mistake in that file. One ip address format is invalid that's the reason for the exception. I have changed the format now it's working fine.

Comment: I just just copied my code from your previous answer in this site! For that  reason I'm accepting this as a answer!